# Apostol's mathematical analysis theorem 1.1

Tags: analysis

Theorem 1.1. Given real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $$a \leq b + \epsilon, \text{ for every } \epsilon \gt 0,\text{ then } a \leq b \tag 1$$
*Proof*. If $$b \lt a,$$ then inequality $(1)$ is violated for $$\epsilon = (a-b)/2 $$because 
$$b + \epsilon = b + (a-b)/2 = (a+b)/2 \lt (a+a)/2 = a $$

I understand Theorem, but I didn't understand the proof part.
why $$\epsilon = (a-b)/2$$ comes out, and what $$b + \epsilon = b + (a-b)/2 = (a+b)/2 \lt (a+a)/2 = a$$ stands for?

Comment: It looks like you're having trouble with the formatting; see [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360).  Note that you can write mathematics with "inline formatting" as follows: `real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a \leq b$, for every $\epsilon > 0$,` and so forth

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I have to learn it. thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

The line
$$
b + \epsilon = b + (a-b)/2 = (a+b)/2 \lt (a+a)/2 = a
$$
stands for a proof of $b+\epsilon < a$, done in several steps:
$$
b + \epsilon = b + (a-b)/2,
\\
b + (a-b)/2 = (a+b)/2
\\
(a+b)/2 \lt (a+a)/2
\\
(a+a)/2 = a
$$

**added**
Why $\epsilon = (a-b)/2$?

In fact, we see in the statement of the theorem, that **any** positive number could be used for $\epsilon$.  This particular choice for $\epsilon$ was made because the calculation (see above) is simple for it.

Comment: It is reasonable, but why ϵ=(a−b)/2 comes? I think that confuses me

Comment: Picking the right constants to use in proofs like this is an art; it is not obvious at first but the more you practice the easier it gets.